# How can I check if an environment variable is set in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I would like to check if an environment variable is set in my [Express JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) server and perform different operations depending on whether or not it is set.

I've tried this:

```
if(process.env.MYKEY !== 'undefined'){
    console.log('It is set!');
} else {
    console.log('No set!');
}
```

I'm testing without the `process.env.MYKEY` but the console prints "It is set".

Comment: Remove the single quotes around 'undefined' and it will work.

Comment: If you're checking for undefined, then you need to use typeof: if(typeof process.env.MYKEY !== 'undefined')

Comment: @ChillyPenguin, to be precise, we should say, that both are valid:

1) `SOMEVAR === undefined` and
2) `typeof SOMEVAR === 'undefined'`,

**but** the second way is preferable because it doesn't use `undefined` as a value

Comment: @maxkoryukov if that's what you are worried about, just use `SOMEVAR === void 0`.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This is working fine in my Node.js project:

```
if(process.env.MYKEY) { 
    console.log('It is set!'); 
}
else { 
    console.log('No set!'); 
}
```

---

EDIT:

Note that, As @Salketer mentioned, depends on the needs, falsy value will be considered as `false` in snippet above. In case a falsy value is considered as valid value. Use `hasOwnProperty` or checking the value once again inside the block.

```
> x = {a: ''}
{ a: '' }
> x.hasOwnProperty('a')
true
```

Or, feel free to use the in operator

```
if ("MYKEY" in process.env) {
    console.log('It is set!');
} else {
    console.log('No set!');
}
```

Comment: Since this seems to get upvoted through the years, I just wanted to point out that it might not produce the expected results if the environment variable's value is a falsy value.

Comment: @Salketer yeah, I guess in case of empty string. It would also meant it has not been set.

Comment: My solution on this question checks for the presence of the key rather than truthiness, so would be more appropriate for falsy string or number values.

Comment: @kucing_terbang, according to documentation `in operator` was mentioned in [ECMA262, 3d Edition (1999)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf#sec-11.8.7) (_page 54_) and was implemented in many old versions of the JS-engines. So no one need to have the newest version of NodeJS, because it is a pretty old feature.

Comment: it still gets the upvotes, though the provided `if(process.env.MYKEY) { .. } else { HERE }` doesn't handle an edge case well: one can reach the `HERE` branch even when the variable is set to an empty string: `MYKEY='' nodejs program.js`

Answer (score 25):

I use this snippet to find out whether the environment variable is set

```js
if ('DEBUG' in process.env) {
  console.log("Env var is set:", process.env.DEBUG)
} else {
  console.log("Env var IS NOT SET")
}
```

---

#### Theoretical Notes

As mentioned in the [NodeJS 8 docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env):

> The `process.env` property returns an object containing the user environment. See [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html).
>
> [...]
>
> Assigning a property on `process.env` will implicitly convert the value to a string.
>
> ```js
>  process.env.test = null
>  console.log(process.env.test);
>  // => 'null'
>  process.env.test = undefined;
>  console.log(process.env.test);
>  // => 'undefined'
> ```

Though, when the variable isn't set in the environment, the appropriate key **is not present** in the `process.env` object at all and the corresponding property of the `process.env` is `undefined`.

Here is another one example (be aware of quotes used in the example):

```js
console.log(process.env.asdf, typeof process.env.asdf)
// => undefined 'undefined'
console.log('asdf' in process.env)
// => false

// after touching (getting the value) the undefined var 
// is still not present:
console.log(process.env.asdf)
// => undefined

// let's set the value of the env-variable
process.env.asdf = undefined
console.log(process.env.asdf)
// => 'undefined'

process.env.asdf = 123
console.log(process.env.asdf)
// => '123'
```

#### A side-note about the code style

I moved this awkward and weird part of the answer away from StackOverflow: [it is here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1954610)

Comment: I just tried to up-vote this answer, but it turned out that it's mine. Life is so ludicrous...

Answer (score 5):

I do practice to use built-in [Node.js assert library](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html).

```
const assert = require('assert');

assert(process.env.MY_VARIABLE, 'MY_VARIABLE is missing');
// or if you need to check some value
assert(process.env.MY_VARIABLE.length > 1, 'MY_VARIABLE should have length greater then 1');
```

I use to add this validation on top of the **index.js**, and keep it up to date with the code requirements.
This way is also easy to check which variables are required for the project, if for some reason .env.example is not in the code.

Here is also updated version that I use, much easy to maintain, and add/remove variables check there:

```js
import assert from 'assert';

let check;
assert(process.env[check = 'PGUSER'], `Environment variable "${check}" is required`);
assert(process.env[check = 'PGHOST'], `Environment variable "${check}" is required`);
assert(process.env[check = 'PGPASSWORD'], `Environment variable "${check}" is required`);
assert(process.env[check = 'PGDATABASE'], `Environment variable "${check}" is required`);
assert(process.env[check = 'PGPORT'], `Environment variable "${check}" is required`);
assert(process.env[check = 'RABBITMQ_URL'], `Environment variable "${check}" is required`);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not check whether the key exists in the environment variables?

```
if ('MYKEY' in Object.keys(process.env))
    console.log("It is set!");
else
    console.log("Not set!");
```

Comment: Which node version is you using? for me just ('MYKEY' in process.env) works on node 10.15.3

Comment: Yes @YuriRodrigoDosSantos that works for me on a new version of node. I avoid using an old one.

Comment: **Wrong answer**. You can't use `in` to determine whether an array contains an item. Check out the docs: [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). In two words - in the answer, you are checking whether the array (as an object) has a property named **MYKEY**. A **property** not an **item**.

Comment: Please, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57648040/1115187

Comment: @maxkoryukov You are correct - `in` checks for properties and not items so is not appropriate. `'length' in ['a']; // true` `'a' in ['a']; // false`.

Answer (score 4):

As the value (if exist) will be a string, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env):

```
process.env.test = null;
console.log(process.env.test);
// => 'null'
process.env.test = undefined;
console.log(process.env.test);
// => 'undefined'
```

and empty string can be returned (that happened to me in CI process + GCP server),

I would create a function to clean the values from `process.env`:

```
function clean(value) {
  const FALSY_VALUES = ['', 'null', 'false', 'undefined'];
  if (!value || FALSY_VALUES.includes(value)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return value;
}

const env = {
  isProduction: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  isTest: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test',
  isDev: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  MYKEY: clean(process.env.MYKEY),
};
 
// Read an environment variable, which is validated and cleaned
env.MYKEY           // -> 'custom values'
 
// Some shortcuts (boolean) properties for checking its value:
env.isProduction    // true if NODE_ENV === 'production'
env.isTest          // true if NODE_ENV === 'test'
env.isDev           // true if NODE_ENV === 'development'
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** (removed old incorrect answer)

As [maxkoryukov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115187/maxkoryukov) said, it should be:

```
# in test.js

if ("TEST_ENV" in process.env) {
    console.log("TRUE: " + process.env["TEST_ENV"])
} else {
    console.log("FALSE")
}
```

This was true with he following test:

```
$> node test.js
FALSE
$> export TEST_ENV="SOMETHING"
$> node test.js
TRUE: SOMETHING
```

This also works when the variable is an empty string (tested in a new bash session/terminal window).

```
$> node test.js
FALSE
$> export TEST_ENV=""
$> node test.js
TRUE:
```

Comment: 1. just a side note: `typeof xxxx === "undefined"` is a canonical way;)

Comment: 2. your code works just fine! but, which one of the recipes is easier to read?

Comment: `if (some_var_name in process.env) { /* your code , if the variable is defined */ }`

Comment: Updated. Please edit if incorrect. Thank you for your correctness.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve easily with || operator with default value attribution case the env var doesn't exist:

```js
const mykey = process.env.MYKEY || '1234';
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. You don't want your production code to run with default values.

Comment: Production will crash if default value or without any value. I don't get your point.

Comment: Will it alway crash cleanly reporting the problem or will it do something unexpected, hard to track down, or even keep running with wrong configuration?

Comment: What is your recommended way to do it?

Comment: How can I check if an environment variable is set in Node.js? Write a validator.

Comment: How do you handle empty or not configured values?

Comment: I would log, report, and prevent the app from doing harm.

Comment: But if you don't know the value correct value, only the default, the maximum you can do is log and break the application.

Comment: the solution has the same issue: env variable with `""` (an empty string) value will be replaced by '1234'. and the question was _"if the variable is set"_, so the provided answer doesn't answer the question, and also can lead to running the app with the wrong configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It's good way to check your environment variable

```
if (process.env.YOUR_ VARIABLE) {
    // If your variable is exist
}
```

Otherwise, If you would like to check multiple environment variables, you can check this `node module` out.

[node-envchecker](https://github.com/maxchou415/node-envchecker)

Comment: An empty string `""` and `undefined` — are definitely different values, but both are **falsey**. But the snippet you provided here can't differentiate them. So, if the variable **is set**, but its value is an empty string (it is legal) your code will behave like the variable is not set. Isn't it an error?

Comment: The same error about the provided package — in the version `1.0.8` ([here](https://github.com/maxchou415/node-envchecker/blob/45a3ffba434e15b739e07ff87557244b54f44230/index.js#L13)) your use the same code to check whether _the variable is **falsey**_

Comment: Please, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57648040/1115187

Answer (score 0):

If you're assigning a value with your if statement, you could do it like this

```
var thisIsSet = 'asddas';
var newVariable = thisIsSet ||'otherValue'
console.log(newVariable)
```

Results in asddas

Comment: Sometimes, I just need to check the presence of the variable and not to play with its value. So, I think, it is not an answer.

Comment: and actually, it is not an answer to the original question, but only a demo of `||` operator

Answer (score -1):

You can create `.env.example` which stores all the required env variable by the application.
After this you can load this `.env.example` and compare with `.env`.

In this way, you can check all the required envs on the time of application start.

To minimize the task, you can use [scan-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scan-env) npm package, which does the same.

```
const scanEnv = require("scan-env");

const scanResult = scanEnv();

if (!scanResult) {
  console.error("Environment variables are missing.");
}
```

[tutorial to use scan-env](https://towardsdatascience.com/scan-environment-variables-in-production-application-4482a4830da1)

Comment: it seems, like in the `main` branch today the code doesn't handle "empty values" for environment variables. So my variable `JOIN_SEPARATOR` will not work (if my program joins values of the array, and I want to join all the elements without any separator, and the default is `,`). Just use the solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57648040/1115187) in this line: https://github.com/schadokar/scan-env/blob/fb8580fe491eb28beda133b10581f8705110bb10/index.js#L28

Answer (score -2):

```
let dotenv;

try {
  dotenv = require('dotenv');
  dotenv.config();
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
  // if vars are not available...
}

//... vars should be available at this point
```

Comment: It's generally better to include a little explanation with your code, to describe how your answer addresses the question and why it differs from the existing accepted answer.

Comment: I had updated the answer with an explanation. Don't know why it is not showing up.

Comment: There are much simpler solutions, without using of 3d-party packages. Moreover, the attached example doesn't show **how to check whether the certain variable `XXX` (or any other) is set in the environment**. In other words, it is not an answer for the OP's question.